# Instantiating Component dynamically in Dart Polymer

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

In the past I used a code like this:

```dart
  var ele=new Element.tag(inActions[key]);
  inputView.append(ele);
  SimInputView view=ele;
  view.logic=TabSimulationElement.logic;
  view.port=port;
  view.applyLogic();
```

Unfortunately I no longer can cast my CustomElements to the Implementation. How can I access the implementation?
Or is the problem that SimInputView is an interface?

For clarification, I can't set logic or port via attributes, because those are not data things, but rather instances of implementations.

Updated: more implementation details.

```html
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="siminput-static">
  <template>
    <div class="">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-right" value="{{value}}" on-input="{{doValidateValue}}">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn {{warning}}" type="button" on-click="{{apply}}">Apply</button>
        </span>
      </div><!-- /input-group -->
    </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="poly_siminput_static.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

And here is an excerpt of the implementation:

```dart
@CustomTag('siminput-static')
class StaticSimInputElement extends PolymerElement implements SimInputView {

  SimLogic _logic;
  ObservablePort _port;

  @observable String value="0";
  int lastValue=0;
  @observable String warning="btn-default";

  StaticSimInputElement.created(): super.created();
}
```

The inAction array contains the tag name like:"siminput-static". I don't see any 404s or other things that point to an error, beside the fact that I get back an HTMLElement and not the implementation.

Comment: You question doesn't tell much about how your element is built (HTML/Dart code). Usually when you can't cast to the class there is a problem with your element (missing import, or similar)

Comment: I added more code for clarification. I don't see any missing imports or anything (the web component is instantiated as expected).

Comment: Can you cast to `StaticSimInputElement`?

Comment: When you inspect the element in the browser and it shows the `ShadowRoot` node it was upgraded fine and casting to the interface should work, otherwise there is a problem with the element.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the DOM. It does have the shadowRoot etc... Also this code used to work already... [DOM](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/562057/DOM.png)

Comment: I think you should file a bug report at http://dartbug.com

Comment: I found the issue. The problem was not the siminput-static, but another one that instantiated yet another Polymer-Element, that in the end caused a NPE during instantiation. Unfortunately that exception was not shown in the console and the ordering of my debug output did not relate to the reported Exception. Thanks for your help!